# PayFlow Pro Template A or B in Mobile

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway, payflowpro

I am experimenting with using Templates A or B in the checkout process. The documentation says they automatically detect and switch to a mobile version but testing seems to show that the templates are the same and the view is simply scaling down.

Can someone confirm that my testing is correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although they look similar they are actually different pages. PayPal auto-detects if the checkout page is being viewed from a supported mobile browser and automatically redirects to the mobile-optimized checkout page.

Comment: What is meant by mobile optimized? During my testing on a phone it looks like the viewport is just scaling down  i.e. all the text boxes get smaller. Should I see something that is different?

Comment: Usually payment buttons match the screen width, etc. Some attributes are scaled down but other elements might be a bit larger or a slightly different shape to optimize the mobile user experience.